# IQ KeyboarManager

Tags: swift, xcode

I am Working on IQKeyboard Manager, But there is a problem; the position or the image of the arrow buttons is opposite for instance.
in the below screenshot: When I am in 2nd TextField(Password) right arrow is active but it should be disabled and up arrow should be enabled instead, vice versa for the next image.

Any Leads for how we can change the image or position of the Buttons?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textfields are probably in reversed order in the document outline in your storyboard.

[image]

make sure the email textfield is above the password textfield.

Comment: Happy to help :)